# UnicodeEncodeError : 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u01e2' in position 8: ordinal not in range(256). How to solve?

Tags: python, urllib

I have to access to a db through this code that is provided by MobiDB to have disorder prediction in proteins.

```
import urllib2
import json

# Define request
acceptHeader = 'My_File_TrEMBL.txt' # text/csv and text/plain supported
request = urllib2.Request("https://mobidb.org/ws/P04050/uniprot", headers={"Accept" : acceptHeader})

# Send request
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

# Parse JSON response di Python dict
data = json.load(response)

# handle data
print(data)
```

Since I'm not using Python 2.6 I changed the script as follows:

```
import urllib.request
import json

# Define request
acceptHeader ='My_File_TrEMBL.txt' 
# text/csv and text/plain supported
request = urllib.request.Request("https://mobidb.org/ws/P04050/uniprot", headers={"Accept" : 
acceptHeader})

# Send request
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)

# Parse JSON response di Python dict
data = json.load(response)

# handle data
print(data)
```

So I am not using urllib2 but urllib.request. The problem arises when the variable request is passed to urllib.request.urlopen that returns me this instance:

" 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u01e2' in position 8: ordinal not in range(256) "

I understood that is something related to ASCII code, but since I am new to Python and I am eager given the deadline of the work I'd like any help you can give me.
Obliged

Comment: You are trying to use an encoding which cannot store this character. Use a Unicode encoding like UTF-8 if you want to print or store arbitrary Unicode characters. Maybe see also the  [Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info) for a brief explanation.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I have this string returned to me : values[i] = one_value.encode('latin-1') that is where the code fails. I would ike to change into ASCII but I don't know how

Comment: So, again, you can't encode Unicode into Latin-1; it's like trying to store a value larger than 255 into a single byte. (A restricted range of Unicode can be encoded as Latin-1, namely code points U+0000 trough U+00FF.) I repeat: read the linked information.

Answer (score 0):

Decode the bytes content using `utf-8` encoding and read the content sing `json.loads`

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
#get the content and decode it using utf-8
respcontent = response.read().decode('utf-8')
data = json.loads(respcontent)

print(data)
```

Comment: The problem is in urllib.request.urlopen. I will try to apply decode to "request". I'll let you know

Comment: might be a issue with `acceptHeader file `  then, although I did not use the file and was able to get the data.